# Querying against a Xml column in a stored procedure

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

I have worked out a query to search a table that contains a column of type `Xml`. The Xml contains a tag called `<rule>` that contains an attribute called `value`

An example of the query that I'm using is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Rulesets
WHERE Ruleset.exist('/ruleset/rule[contains(upper-case(@value), "DEFAULT")]') = 1
```

I would like to be able to create a stored procedure for this query, and pass a parameter to use where the text `DEFAULT` appears.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [sql:variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188254.aspx)

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer.